# Create texture from sprite_sheet coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, glew

I have a sprite_sheet (example sheet):

[image: This is an example, this is not my own authority.]

I loaded as vector data and I need to make a new texture from a specified area. Like this:

```
const std::vector <char> image_data = LoadPNG("sprite_sheet.png"); // This works.

glMakeTexture([0, 0], [50, 50], configs, image_data) //to display only one sqm.
```

[image]

But i don't know how, 'couse mostly GL functions only works in full area, like glTexImage2D.

```
// Only have width and height, the bottomLeft coords is 0, 0 -- I want to change this.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(_sprite_sheet.data[0]));
```

Have a way to do that without load the full sprite_sheet as a texture?

OBS: I'm using picoPNG to decode PNG and I CAN load png, but not make a texture from specified area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you show no code I assume that:

```
char *data; // data of 8-bit per sample RGBA image
int w, h; // size of the image
int sx, sy, sw, sh; // position and size of area you want to crop.
```

`glTexImage2D` does support regions-of-interest. You do it as follows:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, w);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, sx);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, sy);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // LodePNG tightly packs everything
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, sw, sh, border, format, type, data);
```

Comment: @ArnaldoBadin: your edit suggestion is incorrect -- sw is the size of the tile and this is the width of the texture you tried to load. Subtracting `sx` does not make sense because `sw` can be greater than `sx`. For example to crop the head looking left tile you use `sx = 192, sy = 64, sw = 64, sh = 64`, assuming the y-axis going down.

Comment: starts to crop from topLeft (0, 0), -> createTexture(64, 64, 128, 128) normally will display a 64x64 texture, so without this subtraction, glTexImage assume that image size is 128, 128 and display a 128x128 textures in 0.5 scale and the wrong textures. Strange, so this fix that width -x, height - y, saying to GL that my image size is 64x64 from (64, 64) coords.

Comment: Wait a sec, whats the the meaning of your `64, 64, 128, 128`? In my code it is simple, if you want a 64x64 texture then you pass `sw = 64, sh = 64`, where is the problem?

Comment: yep, u're right, it was a code-understanding... my sw and sh re the second-crop-coords. srry, i'm newbie in GL and C++

Comment: But in that case you should have written `sw - sx` rather than `sx - sw` :)

Comment: i wanted to, probably an type error ahaha in my code is right